# Chat com PHP, AJAX e MySQL

Tags: php, ajax

Boas comunidade. Estou a trabalhar neste sistema de chat, muito simples.

Não estou a perceber porque não recebo as mensagens em tempo real. Só consigo receber as mensagens de outro utilizador se fechar e voltar abrir a div, ai a mensagem já aparece.

Como poderei resolver? Como eu não estou muito à vontade com ajax peço a vossa ajuda.

Penso que o problema estará na ultima função, ciclo de mensagens:

```
function message_cycle()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url:'chat.class.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'unread=true',

        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data){             
            $.each(data , function( index, obj ) {
                var user = index;                   
                var box  = $("#jd-chat").find("div#2").parents(".jd-user");

                $(".jd-online").find(".light").hide();

                $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
                    if($.inArray(user,open) !== -1 )                                            
                        $(box).find(".jd-body").append("<span style='display:block'  class='other'> " + value + "</span>");                     
                    else            
                        snd.play();
                        $(".jd-online").find("span#" + user + " .light").show();        


                });
            });             
        }
    });
}

setInterval(message_cycle,1000);
});
```

Alguma ideia?

Descobri onde estava o problema, em vez da div id = 2

`var box  = $("#jd-chat").find("div#2").parents(".jd-user");`

chamei pela `span` que recebe o texto do user sender e do user receiver

`var box  = $("#jd-chat").find(".me").parents(".jd-user");`

ela agora recebe as mensagens e mostra logo as mensagens q existem sem precisar fechar e abrir a div

Comment: Olá vou dar uma sugestão à alguns mêses atrás eu esta va usando o Mibew ele é muito bom, da uma olhada nesse link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWa8svuraC0

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyg_fk36p0Y&list=PLBOh8f9FoHHjz91tWQ5AtBoVwOVhP1Di7 tem aqui tudo o que precisa e a source code https://github.com/howCodeORG/Messenger

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar  e veja se soluciona

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

nos chamados tente

```
$.ajax({ 
url:'chat.class.php',
type:'POST',
cache:false,
...
```

Comment: Olá @Arsom Obrigado pela resposta. coloquei `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` depois da primeira linha do meu documento `$(document).ready(function() {` e continua com o mesmo problema. so recebo as mensagens se fechar a div que recebe as mensagens e voltar chamar ela

Comment: tente usar $.ajax({ url:'chat.class.php', type:'POST',cache:false, nos chamados agora

Comment: coloquei a cache:false, nessa linha do meu documento, e continua a mesma situação.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta atualizar sua div temporariamente...

em Javascript:

```
var tempo = window.setInterval(carrega, 1000);
function carrega()
{
$('#counteudo').load('teste.html');
}
```

em AJAX tem um exemplo aqui:
http://rafaelcouto.com.br/atualizar-div-de-segundos-em-segundos-com-php-xajax/

Comment: não consegui carregar as mensagens com a div aberta. dessa forma ele mostra a div em branco